# Use of Status structure in Plane sweep Algorithm for line Segment Intersection

Tags: c++, algorithm

I want to implement status structure in Plane Sweep algorithm. My sweep line is moving in y-direction from top to bottom.

Currently i am using set(predefined one in c++) for storing segments according to their x values.

When sweep line moves down the x values of each segment changes and hence ordering in set should change, But in set search key once added can not be modified so my x values once assigned are not changed so everytime i move to next eventpoint i have to delete complete tree and create new with new x-values.

My segment structure is:

```
struct Segment
{
    double x1;
    double x2;
    double y1;
    double y2;
    int name;
    double x;
    double y;
};
```

How do i update x values in the set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the solution to the problem. 
Just used orientation to construct AVL tree insted of x-coordinate.

Here is my full source code.

```
#include <string>
#include <queue>
#include <iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include <set>
using namespace std;  
struct Point {
double x;
double y;
int segment;
int segid1;
int segid2;
};
typedef struct Point point;

struct Segment{
double x1;
double x2;
double y1;
double y2;
int name;
double x;
double y;
 };
 typedef struct Segment segment;
 struct classcomp {
  bool operator() (const segment& lhs,const segment& rhs) 
  {//return lhs.x>rhs.x;
   if(rhs.x==lhs.x && rhs.y==lhs.y)
       return ((rhs.x1 - lhs.x2) * (rhs.y2 - lhs.y2) - (rhs.y1 - lhs.y2) *     (rhs.x2 - lhs.x2))<0;
   else
       return ((rhs.x1 - lhs.x1) * (rhs.y2 - lhs.y1) - (rhs.y1 - lhs.y1) * (rhs.x2 - lhs.x1))<0;
   }
    };

class CompareEventPoint {
public:
bool operator()(point& t1, point& t2) // Returns true if t1 is earlier than t2
{
   if(t1.y<t2.y)return true;
   return false;
}
 };


 point checkIntersection(segment a,segment b)
 {
point p;
p.segment=-1;
double num=(a.y1-b.y1)*(b.x2-b.x1)-(a.x1-b.x1)*(b.y2-b.y1);
double den=(a.y1-a.y2)*(b.x2-b.x1)-(a.x1-a.x2)*(b.y2-b.y1);
double s=num/den;
if(s>0 && s<1)
{
    double t=((1-s)*a.x1+s*a.x2-b.x1)/(b.x2-b.x1);
    if(t>0 && t<1)
    {
        p.segment=0;
        if(a.x1>b.x1)
        {
        p.segid1=a.name;
        p.segid2=b.name;
        }
        else
        {
        p.segid1=b.name;
        p.segid2=a.name;    
        }
        p.x=(1-s)*a.x1+s*a.x2;
        p.y=(1-s)*a.y1+s*a.y2;
        return p;
    }
}
return p;

 }

int main()
{
int n,i;
FILE *fp,*f;
priority_queue<point, vector<point>, CompareEventPoint> pq; // Creates a priority queue pq to store strings, and initializes the queue to be empty.
printf("Enter the number of line Segments\n");   
scanf("%d",&n);
segment segArray[n];




point p;
printf("Enter the co-ordinates of End points with top point first and then low  point\n");
  for(i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
    scanf("%lf%lf",&p.x,&p.y);
      p.segment=i+1;
    pq.push(p);
    segArray[i].name=i+1;
    segArray[i].x1=p.x;
    segArray[i].y1=p.y;
    scanf("%lf%lf",&p.x,&p.y);
    p.segment=-(i+1);
    pq.push(p);
    segArray[i].x2=p.x;
    segArray[i].y2=p.y;

}


set<segment,classcomp> tree;
set<segment,classcomp>::iterator itlow,itup;
int segid;
point ptemp;
double lineY;
int iteration=0;
while (!pq.empty()) {

   ptemp=pq.top();
   pq.pop(); 
   iteration++; 
   segid=ptemp.segment;
   lineY=ptemp.y;
   // Case of starting Point

   for (itlow=tree.begin(); itlow!=tree.end();++itlow)
        printf("%d\t",itlow->name);
   printf("\n");



   if(segid>0)
   {

   tree.insert(segArray[segid-1]);
   itlow=tree.lower_bound (segArray[segid-1]);   
   if(itlow!=tree.begin())                                                  //       ^
   {    itlow--;
       p=checkIntersection(segArray[segid-1],segArray[itlow->name-1]);
       if(p.segment==0 && ptemp.y>p.y)
       {
           pq.push(p);

       }
   }

   itup=tree.upper_bound (segArray[segid-1]); 
   if(itup!=tree.end())
   {

           p=checkIntersection(segArray[segid-1],segArray[itup->name-1]);
           if(p.segment==0 && ptemp.y>p.y)
           {
               pq.push(p);
           }
   }
   }


   // Case of intersection Point
   if(segid==0)
   {
       int t1=ptemp.segid1;
       int t2=ptemp.segid2;


       segment s1=segArray[t1-1];
       segment s2=segArray[t2-1];


       tree.erase(s1); 
       tree.erase(s2); 


       segArray[t1-1].x=ptemp.x;
       segArray[t1-1].x1=ptemp.x;
       segArray[t2-1].x=ptemp.x;
       segArray[t2-1].x1=ptemp.x;
       segArray[t1-1].y=ptemp.y;
       segArray[t1-1].y1=ptemp.y;
       segArray[t2-1].y=ptemp.y;
       segArray[t2-1].y1=ptemp.y;

       s1=segArray[t1-1];
       s2=segArray[t2-1];

       tree.insert(s1);
       tree.insert(s2);


       itlow=tree.lower_bound (s1);
       if(itlow!=tree.begin())
       {       itlow--;
               p=checkIntersection(s1,segArray[itlow->name-1]);

               if(p.segment==0 && ptemp.y>p.y)
                  {
                   pq.push(p);
                  }
       }
       itup=tree.upper_bound (s2); 
       if(itup!=tree.end())
       {

           p=checkIntersection(s2,segArray[itup->name-1]);
           if(p.segment==0 && ptemp.y>p.y)
            {
               pq.push(p);
            } 
       }


       printf("Intersection point=%lf %lf\n",ptemp.x,ptemp.y);

   }

   // Case of End point
   if(segid<0)
   {



       segid=-segid;
       if(itlow!=tree.begin() && itup!=tree.end())
       {
       itlow=tree.lower_bound (segArray[segid-1]);
       itlow--;
       itup=tree.upper_bound (segArray[segid-1]); 
       }
       tree.erase(segArray[segid-1]); 
       if(itlow!=tree.begin() && itup!=tree.end())
       {
       p=checkIntersection(segArray[itlow->name-1],segArray[itup->name-1]);
       if(p.segment==0 && ptemp.y>p.y)
       {
           pq.push(p);
       }

       }

   }
}

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`std::set` is generally implemented as a red-black tree. The ordering of elements in the tree is controlled by passing pairs of elements to a comparison function which is stored in the `set`; an element's position within the sort order is checked during insertion, and is assumed not to change thereafter. (You probably know all this already... just giving some background.)

Plane-sweep algorithms also commonly use self-balancing trees such as red-black trees for their state structure. However-- that's where the similarity ends. Elements (segments) in the state structure have no inherent overall ordering; the order is defined given a particular y-coordinate, and will change with the y-coordinate. Most importantly, at intersection event points, two segments will *swap positions* in the ordering, an operation that doesn't even make sense with `std::set`.

Bottom line: `std::set`, and other sorted container classes, are generally not appropriate for implementing the sweep state of a plane-sweep algorithm, even though the underlying data structures are appropriate. You should use a lower-level, directly-exposed red-black tree implementation which will allow you to swap elements.

Comment: Thanks @Sneftel for the quick reply. So if i implement myself AVL tree how do you suggest swapping of elements at EventPoints as lot of segments order might change.

Comment: Basically, you just swing pointers around. Take all the segments which are participating in the event point, and find their new ordering. Then make the first segment in the new ordering point to the parent and children of the first segment in the old ordering, etc. (Note: This is easiest to do out-of-place, and requires parent pointers.)